# Incorrect rendering when using NSTextView with TextKit 1

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nstextview, textkit

I encountered some issues with rendering in `NSTextView`. When I'm hitting enter the last line rendering is lagging and the line is not visible. Also, sometimes when I hit backspace the last line is temporarily duplicated.

The problem is presented on the video: [here](https://github.com/wojciech-kulik/Swift-Crazy-iBugs/assets/3128467/535c0fdb-0fb7-45f5-a43a-91d6adb79d94).

Code to reproduce the issue:

```swift
    func bug() {
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
        textContainer.widthTracksTextView = true
        textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: "")

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        let textView = NSTextView(frame: .zero, textContainer: textContainer)
        textView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]

        // The case that presents the bug:
        textView.string = "\naaaaa\nbbbbbb"
        textView.setSelectedRange(.init(location: 0, length: 0))

        let scrollView = NSScrollView()
        scrollView.documentView = textView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

In general, it looks like it is a problem with TextKit 1. If I use TextKit 2, it works fine:

```swift
    func textKit2NoBug() {
        let textView = NSTextView(usingTextLayoutManager: true)
        textView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]

        // The case that presents the bug:
        textView.string = "\naaaaa\nbbbbbb"
        textView.setSelectedRange(.init(location: 0, length: 0))

        let scrollView = NSScrollView()
        scrollView.documentView = textView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

However, in my case, I have to rely on TextKit 1. Does anyone know how to workaround this issue?

Full source code: [here](https://github.com/wojciech-kulik/Swift-Crazy-iBugs/tree/main/AppKit/TextViewBug)

Comment: Did you find anything that fixed this? I have been struggling with multiple TextKit 1 rendering issues on Sonoma, which cause full line fragments to "breathe" (change position) when caret is rendered. If you ever found any solutions to your issue, it could help with mine as well.

Comment: @Tritonal I reported this issue and it was solved with the latest Xcode. At least it's not reproducible anymore. However, I'm not sure if you have the same problem. Mine you can try reproducing using this code: https://github.com/wojciech-kulik/Swift-Crazy-iBugs/tree/main/AppKit/TextViewBug

Comment: I encountered even weirder stuff myself, including this bug. It's still happening in the latest Xcode and macOS Sonoma for me, but I'm on Intel. I've submitted feedback to Apple as well, let's hope they'll figure out a fix at some point.